# Get size of audio while recording android?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am working on an android application .  I am recording audio using MediaRecorder class. I want to check size of recorded audio while recording and check size of recorded audio  if size greater than certain MB I want stop recording . How can I achieve this . any help will be appreciated .
public class RecordAudio {

```
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

public RecordAudio() {
}

//
public void prepareRecording(String fileName) {

    if (mRecorder == null) {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(app.appExternalDir + "/" + fileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        System.out.println("this is max::::"+mRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}

// This starts the recording of the voice memo
public void startRecording() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.start();
    }

}

// This stops the recording and save the data on storage
public void stopRecording() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: So, what have you tried, Can you post your desire code ?

Answer (score 0):

use below code to get size of your recorded file

```
 try{
                 File file = new File(path_of_your_recorded_file);
                 long length = file.length();
                 length = length/1024;
                 System.out.println("File Path : " + file.getPath() + ", File size : " + length +" KB");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("File not found : " + e.getMessage() + e);
            }
```

then once you get length you can chek as per your requirement hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For those who came across this now:

There is an Interface that you can implement :

```
public class RecordingService extends Service implements 
  MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener{

  @Override
  public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    Log.d(TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE,"inside the onInfo");
    //check whether file size has reached to Max size to stop recording
    if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE,"Media exceeded the size");
    }
  }
}
```

And In your MediaRecorder initialisation code you can set the interface callback and size
eg:

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setMaxFileSize(Audio_MAX_FILE_SIZE);
```

Hope it helps